# Multiple Y-scale in different columns

Tags: achartengine

I have multiple y-scales, it works perfect. However, it would be more impressive if y-values would displayed in seperate columns, near the y axis.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do something similar to what you need but maybe not exactly that. You can align the first scale on right and the second scale on left such as the values do not overlap:

```
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);
```

Comment: I know this way, but unfortunately to display on the left side is a request for me. Otherwise it's good solution, if I have only two series, but when more than two series are displayed, overlapping comes again. What do you suggest?

Comment: In this case, the only suggestion is that you checkout the ACE source code and extend it the way you need.